No Exception when Internet not available in HTTP Request
When doing a HTTP request in Flutter I do not get any Exception like SocketException when WiFi is on but there is actually no internet, rather it waits long time until I get the defined TimeoutException. Also this issue appears when there is network connection in the beginning but suddenly the connection drops.
How do I make it that it directly gives an exception whenever network issues occur?
This my current code:
try {
  await http
      .get(url, headers: headers)
      .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 20));
} on SocketException catch (e, st) {
  debugPrint('SocketException. Seems to be no internet available');
  debugPrint(e.toString());
  debugPrint('OS Errorcode: ${e.osError?.errorCode.toString()}');
} catch (e, st) {
  debugPrint('Unknown error happen in `tryAndHandle`:');
}


For that you have use ping some URL to check if the connection is available or not. This package seems to provide such ping mechanism ..

@SpiritCrusher so before each request i should ping the url? I don't think this is an optimal way to avoid this issue since it'll consume lots of data and there's still the case that the network can drop after the ping during the actual network request so it'll wait until time-out...

I'm not sure is it only an http package request issue or are there other http request packages that avoid those issues mentioned?

Add catch clause for TimeoutException, which is not an "unknown error". Generally speaking, SocketException occurs before any TimeoutException would occur.

@MartinZeitler i did add timeout exception however when during the network call the network drops or when there is wifi but no actual Internet connection exist then no exception is thrown except my defined timeout exception after x seconds which is not good. It should return directly an exception.

To manage this problem, you can implement several strategies.
First, before issuing the HTTP request, you can check if you have Internet connectivity. For this i suggest using the connectivity_plus package: https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus
You can easily subscribe to a stream that give you the current Internet Status like this:
bool isConnected = false;

StreamSubscription<List<ConnectivityResult>> subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((List<ConnectivityResult> result) {
    // Received changes in available connectivity types!
    // Add here your bool var to indicate wether there is Internet connection or not.
    if (connectivityResult.contains(ConnectivityResult.mobile) ||
        connectivityResult.contains(ConnectivityResult. ethernet) ||
        connectivityResult.contains(ConnectivityResult.wifi) ) {
        isConnected = await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
    }
    else {
        isConnected = false;
    }
  });

Once done, you can check the boolean that indicate the Internet connection status BEFORE issuing your http request.
Then you need to handle a loss of Internet connection during the request.
Here you can handle http errors like timeouts. Note that this will also handle network or servers errors too.
try {
  http.Response response = await http.get('myUrl').
      timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // handle HTTP error
  }
} on TimeoutException catch (e) {
  // Certainly a network error, but not only...
  print('Timeout Error: $e');
} on SocketException catch (e) {
  // Handle here socket error
  print('Socket Error: $e');
} on Error catch (e) {
  // Handle here other errors
  print('General Error: $e');
}

In your example you indicates a 20s timeout value, i recommend shortened this to something like 5/6 s value except if you know that your request will be longer.
EDIT
If you don't want to wait until the timeout arise, you cas try to manage your own with a wraper function that try to intercept the Internet connectivity change (not tested):
Future<void> myHttpRequest() async {
  // Instantiate a completer
  Completer completer = Completer();

  // Start a periodic time that will check the Internet connectivity
  // through the bool that is populate with the connectivity stream
  Timer checkConnectivityTime = Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(
        milliseconds: 100,
      ), (timer) {
    if (!isConnected) {
      if (timer.isActive) {
        timer.cancel();
      }
      completer.completeError('Internet connectivity lost');
    }
  });

  // Make your HTTP request
  try {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('myUrl')).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // do something
      // And don't forget to complete the completer
      completer.complete();
    } else {
      // handle HTTP error
      // And don't forget to complete the completer with complete() or completeError(), as you need.
      completer.complete();
    }
  } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
    // Certainly a network error, but not only...
    // And don't forget to complete the completer
      completer.completeError('Timeout Error: $e');
  } on SocketException catch (e) {
    // Handle here socket error
    // And don't forget to complete the completer
      completer.completeError('Socket Error: $e');
  } on Error catch (e) {
    // Handle here other errors
    // And don't forget to complete the completer
      completer.completeError('General Error: $e');
  }

  return completer.future;
}

Then you can call this function like this:
myHttpRequest().then((value) {
  // Do what you need 
}).catchError((error){
  // Manage your error
});

EDIT 2
I have updated the check Internet connectivity code snipet to also use the internet_connection_checker package. So in case connectivity_plus notify wifi, ethernet or mobile network, check the connectivity with internet_connection_checker which ping some servers to be sure there is an active Internet conexion.

The ConnectivityResult does not proof that there is actually an internet connection i tired it.

Can you specify what you do for testing?

Have modify my answer, see EDIT 2

connectivity_plus cannot tell you whether there is actually an Internet connection - it's written at the top of the README. A network might be connected, but have no connection to a router to reach the Internet.

@JaffaKetchup in that case you can do ping request on server and check if you are getting reply or not

use internet_connection_checker package
https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker
To check use this code:
 bool internetStatus = await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
--Extra: another approach (which is not as you want but it may help you) is to know the internet status on the App-level, this idea worked for my app logic,
I notify the user about the internet status (by viewing the no internet screen) before sending an API request.
Example:
Put a StreamProvider which holds and updates the InternetConnectionStatus as a stream whenever the value changes.
In your main.dart or myapp.dart:
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MultiProvider(
     providers: [
       StreamProvider<InternetConnectionStatus>(
         initialData: InternetConnectionStatus.connected,
         create: (_) {
           return InternetConnectionChecker().onStatusChange;
         },
       ),
     ],
     child: MaterialApp(
       debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
       home: Consumer<InternetConnectionStatus>(
         builder: (context, connectionStatus, _) {
           if (connectionStatus == InternetConnectionStatus.connected) {
             return const MyHomePage();
           } else {
             return const NoInternetScreen();
           }
         },
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}



SocketException somehow does not detect no internet connect what I am using is something like normal Exception it does get triggered only when internet is not available or when request does not proceed. All other Exceptions like timeout etc.. are return as form of http.Response object, you can handle them through that.
@override
Future<http.Response?> putHttp(
  {required String endPoint,
  Duration timeOut = const Duration(seconds: timeOutDuration),
  Map<String, String>? headers,
  Map<String, dynamic>? requestBody}) async {
try {
  // call http request
  http.Response response = await http
      .put(
        Uri.parse(endPoint),
        body: requestBody,
        headers: headers,
      )
      .timeout(timeOut);

  return response;
} on Exception catch (_) {
  return null;
}
}


It does not go even to the standard catch block so there's no difference

I am using it is doing just fine when no internet connection I get null response due to which I am able to show error message

Actually there is no way to do this without pinging different urls to make sure there is internet.
Or use flutter_offline to detect changes and response accordingly.

